# Why does the whole program loop again when I run it? After depositing or withdrawing money from an account, it asks for a username again

Tags: python, sqlite, debugging

```
# PHASE 1 (FILE I/O with One Customer)
# Initialization of Current Balance ** Current Balance is the same for all users for the sake of simplicity ** 
myMoney = open("current_balance.txt")
currentBalance = int(myMoney.readline())

# Imports 
import sqlite3

# Creation of Bank Account and Notifying User(s) of Current Balance
class Bank_Account:
    def __init__(self):
        self.balance= currentBalance
        print("Welcome to Your Bank Account System!")
    # If statements for first screen
    def options_1(self):
        ch = int(input("1. Create an Account\n2. Log into Your Account\nEnter a Choice: "))
        if ch == 1: 
            self.create()
        if ch == 2: 
            self.Log_in()
    def options_2(self): 
        ch= int(input("1. Withdraw Money from Your Account\n2. Deposit Money to Your Account\nEnter a Choice: "))
        if ch == 1: 
            self.withdraw()
        if ch == 2: 
            self.deposit()
    # Function to Create an Account 
    def create(self): 
        user_create = str(input("Enter a Username:"))
        pin_create = int(input("Enter a Pin Number:" ))
        print("Account successfully created!")
     # Function to Log into Account 
    def Log_in(self):
        user = str(input("Enter your username:"))
        pin = int(input("Enter your Pin Number:")) 
        print("Welcome", user, "!")
    # Function to Deposit Money 
    def deposit(self):
        amount=float(input("Enter the amount you want to deposit: "))
        self.balance += amount
        print("Amount Deposited: ",amount)
        print("Net Available Balance=",self.balance)
    # Function to Withdraw Money
    def withdraw(self):
        amount = float(input("Enter the amount you want to withdraw: "))
        if self.balance>=amount:
            self.balance-=amount
            print("You withdrew: ",amount)
            print("Net Available Balance=",self.balance)
        else:
            print("Insufficient balance ")

    def display(self):
        print("Net Available Balance=",self.balance)

# Creating an object of class
self = Bank_Account()
# Calling functions with that class
self.options_1()
self.options_2()
self.create()
self.display()



# PHASE 2 (With Database)

# Define Connection and Cursor 
connection = sqlite3.connect('Bank_Users.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

# Create Users Table 
command1 = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
bank(pin INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username TEXT)"""
cursor.execute(command1)

# Add to Users/Bank
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bank VALUES (7620, 'Kailas Kurup')")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bank VALUES (4638, 'Bethany Watkins')")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bank VALUES (3482, 'John Hammond')")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bank VALUES (3493, 'Melissa Rodriguez')")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bank VALUES (9891, 'Gopalakrishnan Nair')")

# Get Results 
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM bank")
results = cursor.fetchall()
print(results)
```

This is my code so far. I have not completed the database portion of this project yet. I'm trying to create a bank account management system where the user can create an account, log in, and withdraw/deposit money from that account. After completing the database portion of this project I plan on adding Tkinter GUI.

Comment: You're calling `self.create()` in the top-level code, and also in the `options_1()` method. Both of them ask for the username.

Comment: Just get rid of the extra call to `self.create()` after `self.options_2()`.

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't use `self` as a regular variable. This is conventionally used as the first argument to methods in classes. Using it for anything else is confusing, it looks like you got the indentation wrong for code that should be in a method.